# spatie/laravel-permissions - Gate and hasPermissionTo are not working

Tags: laravel, permissions, laravel-permission

I have a problem with `spatie/laravel-permissions`...

I use `Gate` in `AuthServiceProvider.php` to define `Superadmin` (can bypass all permissions without register it to the role)...

It is working perfectly with `can('the-permission')` helper.

But it is not working with `Auth::user()->hasPermissionTo('the-permission')`...

.

.

Below is my code:

.

In `AuthServiceProvider.php`:

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->registerPolicies();

    Gate::before(function ($user, $ability) {
        $superadmin_rolename = 'Superadmin';
        $guard_name = 'web-admin';
        return $user->hasRole($superadmin_rolename , $guard_name ) ? true : null;
    });
}
```

.

.

In Blade:

```
@can('add products')
    <button type="submit">Add Product</button>
@endcan

// this will work perfectly, the button will be shown
```

.

.

In Controller:

```
public function addProduct()
{
    $admin = Auth::guard('web-admin')->user();

    if($admin->hasPermissionTo('add products')) return true;

    return false;
}

// this is not working (it return false)... i dont know why.... it should return true....
```

so, as what I show to you above:

- I use `Gate` to define superadmin
- the superadmin should grant all access
- it is working perfectly with `can()` and `$user->can()`
- but it is not working with `$user->hasPermissionTo()` <--------- this is what i want to know

Thanks

Comment: `hasPermissionTo` only checks the database, it does not run `gate::before`, [this](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission/issues/1062#issuecomment-472953165) should answer your question.

Comment: thanks for sharing the answer....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @Remul's comment, I found that only `can()` or `$user->can()` will work perfectly with `Gate::before`....

So, how if I want to use another method like `$user->hasAnyPermission` or `$user->hasAllPermissions` ?

.

This is what I do...I decided to create a custom method in the `Admin` model..

```
<?php

namespace Model;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles;

class Admin extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasRoles;

    protected $guard_name = "web-admin";

    protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'password'];

    public function canAny(array $permissions)
    {
        foreach($permissions as $e){
            if($this->can($e)) return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public function canAll(array $permissions)
    {
        foreach($permissions as $e){
            if(!$this->can($e)) return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I wrote the two functions directly in my User-Modal. I took function names (hasAnyPermission & hasAllPermissions) from Spatie and that works.